# Restoring old wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

I am trying to restore an old bitcoin backup i found in my google drive.

The original backup date is 2013, and i am quite interested to see if there is any money on it :)

I tried to follow this https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover.md but i get an error stating : Unknown wallet version from the future

I found the file named "secret.backup" and i just changed it to "wallet" with no type.

Opening the file in nodepad, the only readable part is : org.bitcoin.production

My end goal would be to check for funds, and transfer to my exodus client

Comment: You should make clear which wallet you were using, at first I assumed you were talking about Bitcoin Core but it seems not.
I would have suggested you directly open an issue on the wallet github as they are more likely to be able to help you, but it seems they have a backlog of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken another crack at it, and ended up succeding.
I followed this guide: https://walletsrecovery.org/recovery-docs/bitcoinwallet-recovery.html

BUT i cloned and older repository, i choose release 0.11 as it came out in 2014 and i saw my backup was from 2013.

It is now succesfully syncing.